# What is a "whorl of dried sticks"?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

What is a "whorl of dried sticks"?

The words are written in [this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=tSYPVAqJ548C&pg=PA253&lpg=PA253&dq=%22whorl+of+dried+sticks%22&source=bl&ots=wHptIXPGn0&sig=MMjKtK8sl2wyE8NgEIpESLTkS8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR7s6yz9PLAhWIipQKHRV-CQAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22whorl%20of%20dried%20sticks%22&f=false).

> I would vow that in the future I would not wait for the imminence of death to say, *I love you, thank you, please forgive me, I forgive you, good-bye.* I would settle her estate, take down her photographs and **whorl of dried sticks** she'd hung over the fireplace, and give my brother Jonathan her Bernina sewing machine and my brother Michael a quilt she'd sewn of patches of Japanese indigo, under which she and my father once slept.

Comment: This text is not available to me; can you quote the passage? But first, did you look up *whorl* in a dictionary? The literal meaning is quite unambiguous.

Comment: I think it might  be similar to *fanned ginger snaps*. A whirl, when you look it up, will include a type of pattern. But more context is necessary, as it could be something (very) different.

Comment: Well, now that we have the passage, I'm going to say that this is a dictionary reference question, unlike the other one, where the meaning of *fanned* cannot be found in a learner's dictionary.

Comment: Whorl: "a pattern of spirals or concentric circles."  It sounds to me like dried sticks, woven into a spiral pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I presume this to be a group of sticks grouped together to decorate the fireplace, above the mantle. You will sometimes see this in cottages or country-style homes. The sticks may be arranged in a whorl, or a circular pattern like a wreath.